# Transfer function of an RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, control, transfer-function

I'm trying to find the transfer function of the circuit below. I am aware there are tutorials available online for similar circuits, and I have tried them. But I cannot confirm whether my answer for this is correct. I am more looking for the answer rather than the process, but the process would also be appreciated to confirm my own.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This looks like homework, imho. If you show your work (and your answer) you will get a better response. Homework questions with no attempt (shown) are typically closed.

Comment: `But I cannot confirm whether my answer for this is correct.` Can you show us what you've done so far? That way, we can give you feedback based on what you know already.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question with no effort shown

Comment: This is not homework, it is study for a repeat exam in a module i cannot wrap my head around, and i don't have access to my lecturer to help. I understand you don't want the forum to be spammed, but i'm just trying to learn. This will likely be my only post before closing the account, so nobody gains from closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aye ? its basicly vout/vin so we need to find vout -

First we try to simply the circuit -> C and R2 are in series, so (1/jwc + R2)
So laplace transform of C is 1/cs and lapace of R is just R.
Then I see a voltage divider configuration

So we have Vout = Vin*(R2+1/cs)/R1+(R2+1/cs)

now isolate Vout/Vin and voilá .. theres G(s)

Comment: Sorenp, that's perfect. thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah no worries, just keep it simple, and always look to reduce the complexity of circuits one step at a time.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the fast analytical circuits techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371), you'll obtain the transfer function by inspecting the circuit without writing a single line of algebra. Furthermore, it will be presented in a *low-entropy* form giving you insight on where the poles and zeroes are placed.

Start with \$s=0\$: open the capacitor, what is the gain \$H_0\$ linking \$V_{in}\$ (the stimulus) to the response \$V_{out}\$? \$H_0=1\$.

Now, reduced the excitation to 0 V (replace \$V_{in}\$ by a wire) and "look" through the capacitor's connections to determine the resistance: you "see" that \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are in series leading to a time constant \$\tau=(R_1+R_2)C_1\$. The pole in this 1st-order system is the inverse of the time constant: \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{(R_1+R_2)C_1}\$.

For the zero, look for the condition nulling the response: if you apply a stimulus \$V_{in}\$ what condition would make \$V_{out}=0\$? If the series connection of \$C_1\$ and \$R_2\$ forms a short circuit:\$R_2+\frac{1}{sC_1}=0\$. Solving this simple equation gives a zero \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{R_2C_1}\$.

The complete transfer function is therefore: \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{1}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{1}{\omega_p}}\$. This is the *low-entropy* form you need to adopt to express transfer functions the right way.

Nothing complicated here, just a few steps to determine the time constants in two conditions: when the stimulus is turned off and when the response is nulled.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we know that:

$$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{V}_\text{out}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{V}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_2}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1}=\frac{1+\text{sCR}_2}{1+\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\cdot\text{sC}}\tag1$$